# Using NSURLProtocol with ReactNative

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

We have a WebView application were we are using NSURLProtocol to intercept all javascript calls in native. Now we are planning to use ReactNative but when we try the same it is giving below error:

No suitable request handler found.

Looks like ReactNative is intercepting all the calls and we need to register our class to listen for the URL request. We have searched on internet but could not found much document. Please help us on this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using native modules? This repository uses NSURLProtocol in React Native. https://github.com/enu-kuro/ReactNative-Adblock-WebView